# how to have pause/play functionality in slideshow

Tags: android, multithreading, slideshow

I have few images which i am showing as a slideshow. after every image i have a blank image. the code is working fine. i want to put play/pause functionality it in. Like when the user touches the screen in between the slideshow it should be paused and a button should be displayed for play/pause. this is my code:

```
public class TatSlideShow extends Activity {

int count = 1;
private ImageView tatslide;
int i = 0;
int imgid[] = { R.drawable.tata1, R.drawable.tata2, R.drawable.tata3,
        R.drawable.tata4, R.drawable.tata5 };
RefreshHandler refreshHandler = new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TatSlideShow.this.updateUI();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
};

public void updateUI() {

    refreshHandler.sleep(3000);

    if ((count & 1) == 0) {

        tatslide.setImageResource(0);
        count++;
    } else {

        if (i < imgid.length) {
            tatslide.setImageResource(imgid[i]);

            // imageView.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
            i++;
            count++;
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tatslideshow);

    this.tatslide = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.tatslide);
    updateUI();
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: the problem is i dont have a clue where to start from. maybe i should put an onclicklistener on the imageview. but how do i stop the thread when imageview is clicked?